# Getting TypeError: t.replace is not a function Vue.js

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

```
        this.$http.post('../idea/comment'+idea_id, newResponse).then((response) => {
            //do something

            }, (response) => {

            });

        //get returned comment
        //update DOM
       },
     }
 });
```

All get request run fine but I keep getting this error when trying the Post request.

[image]

Comment: Since you have no replace in your code, you must not be showing us the correct block.

Comment: Try correcting the url to 'idea/comment/' + idea_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found what i was doing wrong, i didn't declare the CSRF token global correctly.

I did this

`Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel;`

instead of

`Vue.http.headers.common['X-CSRF-TOKEN'] = window.Laravel.csrfToken;`